# How to show lines matching search in open folds in vim?

Tags: search, vim, folding

How can I show all lines in only open folds that match "foo"?

I tried this per ["search only in folded text"](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_only_in_unfolded_text):

```
:folddoopen g/foo
```

but got this error: `E147: Cannot do :global recursive`

vim version: 7.3 (2010 Aug 15)

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.  If all you want is to see the lines that match rather than also move the cursor there, the solution is to turn on `hlsearch` (see `:help 'hlsearch').  Closed folds will stay closed, so you won't see any matches inside. :)

Comment: You can't use `:foldd[oopen]` followed by `global` because `foldd` is essentially a `global` command itself (except that instead of taking of pattern for lines on which to apply `cmd` it automatically does that for all non-folded lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:folddoopen` and `:g` cannot be used together in a meaningful way.
Instead, use `:g` with `foldclosed()`:

```
:g/foo/if foldclosed('.') == -1 | # | endif
```

For more help see:

```
:help :g
:help /
:help :if
:help foldclosed()
:help :#
:help :foldopen
```

Comment: No, that actually returns all the lines.

Comment: Closer, but that returns the lines in the closed fold.

Comment: `foldclosed('.')` returns `-1` for a line that is not in a closed fold. I have tested it and it only shows lines that match `foo` that are not on closed lines.

Comment: My fault, I don't know what I was doing wrong, but it now works for me.  Well done @Peter_Rincker -- thank you for a solution!